# Laravel Nova gate doesn't stop from entering login in production

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I implemented Laravel Nova as admin panel for my application. I'm not using the default guard for authentication, instead I use an admin guard and admin users table. Everything works fine.

Now I wanted to implement it to the production server. However, the gate is not working, since every user can still enter the Nova login at *myapplication.com/nova*. This should only be possible in a local environment.

I even tried to change the return of the gate to false, however it seems that nova is not entering the gate function either.

My *NovaServiceProvider.php* looks like this:

```
protected function gate()
    {
        Gate::define('viewNova', function ($user) {
            return false;
        });
    }
```

Why doesn't Nova enter the gate, even on production server? Is there any chance to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Configure the Telescope authorization services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function authorization()
{
    $this->gate();

    Telescope::auth(function ($request) {
        return app()->environment('local') ||
               Gate::any(['viewTelescope', 'Access Telescope'], [$request->user()]);
    });
}
```

Try overriding the authorization method